# Unity: Any way to get anti-aliasing on Screen Space - Overlay Canvas?

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, antialiasing

I'm using Unity and I have a Screen Space - Overlay canvas and it has Image objects that rotate. The problem is that on shallow rotations the images have really obvious jagged edges. I can't find any built in anti-aliasing solution that fixes this.

[image]

I know the MSAA in the settings doesn't apply to overlay canvases, neither does the anti-aliasing in the Post Effects package.

I can't change to a Screen Space - Camera canvas, I know that will apply MSAA but it breaks my game in too many other ways to be viable (my game is almost finished, I left adding AA to the end which may have been a mistake).

Is there any way to get AA to work on an overlay canvas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution is in [the second answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/142951/99668) in [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/139626/is-ui-anti-aliasing-broken-in-unity-5-6) on Game Development Stack Exchange: add a transparent outline to your image.

> Enabling mip-maps gets you half way there, but the other half of it is to make sure that sides you want smoothed are bordered by alpha transparency. The outer edge of everything you want smooth must be transparent.