# Screen space camera canvas aliasing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a number of images and text mesh pro assets on a **screen space camera** canvas (not **overlay**, so [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62706913/unity-any-way-to-get-anti-aliasing-on-screen-space-overlay-canvas) is not a dup) with a 45 deg FOV perspective camera and I'm getting jaggies on every asset that is rotated on an axis other than 0, 90, 180, 270 deg.

[image]

- Images and text mesh pro are equally affected.
- The plane distance from camera makes no difference, nor does the
  scale or size of the assets.
- I have a canvas scaler but no settings change the aliasing.
- I'm using post processing stack 3.2.2. I've tried all 3 AA methods,
  each has a slightly different effect but the aliasing is always quite
  noticeable.
- I've disabled the post processing in case it's another effect but no
  change.
- Changing Anti Aliasing in quality settings to affect the cameras MSAA
  has no effect at all.
- Because images and text are affected equally - including the default
  image sprite in the above picture - I don't think mip map settings
  etc are the issue.
- I've increased atlas resolution to max for the TMPro assets to no
  effect.

Anything else I can try?

Cross posted on [GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/201313/screen-space-camera-canvas-aliasing) and [UnityAnswers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1906986/screen-space-camera-canvas-aliasing.html)

Comment: Do you mean this is a render texture? What resolution do you have the target set to? It could be that you're rendering to a small texture and you've stretched it, which is exaggerating the aliasing.

Comment: @Chuck - Just normal Image and TextMeshPro components, no render textures. The screenshot above is an unscaled section of a 3440 x 1440 screenshot, showing a default sprite of w100 x h100. There is a correlation between resolution and scale of aliasing as you'd expect but nothing out of the ordinary in this case.

Comment: Yeah but that's what I'm saying, I think - you're stretching the sprite 34x in one direction and 14x in the other direction.

Comment: What Unity version are you on? I have a project that uses 2021.3 and have no issues with aliasing. Uses screen space camera too, and has AA set in the Quality settings. Hard to tell the difference without seeing your settings.

Comment: @Chuck The screenshot above is from the default sprite at 100 x 100 width. None of the canvas scalers make a difference and lower resolutions have minimal effect so i don't think that's it. Also, the issue doesn't exist when using screen space overlay

Comment: @frankhermes 2021.3. For testing I maxed out all the quality settings.